# How do I avoid audio from disappearing when using `Tone.PolySynth()` with `Sequence` method?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, web-audio-api, tone.js

#### Context

I've been trying to build a step sequencer similar to the [official example](https://tonejs.github.io/examples/stepSequencer) in `Tone.js` documentation. Instead of using playing MP3 files with `Players` method, however, I wanted to implement `PolySynth` to explore a variety of sounds like [Jon Oliver's example](https://jonoliver.codes/sequencer/).

After looking at a few demos with different approaches—like [this drum sequencer](https://codesandbox.io/s/sequencer-demo-wjgg4?file=/src/Sequencer.js) (using MP3s with `Players`), [this step sequencer](https://medium.com/geekculture/creating-a-step-sequencer-with-tone-js-32ea3002aaf5#d7bc) (using several mono `Synth`s)—I managed to build a basic functioning sequencer. [My working demo in CodeSandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/tonejs-sequencer-exploration-ixetox?file=/src/App.tsx).

#### Problem

While it works as intended—i.e. playing individual notes when toggled on/off, looping the sequence per defined speed, toggling the play/pause mode, etc—**the polysynth sound starts to get a little distorted after a few loops and soon becomes completely mute**.

Even after the audio disappears, the `Sequence` call seems to continue and all other features do work as intended—but it becomes noticeably stuttering and laggy.

I suspect it's the way I'm handling `Sequence` call and unintentionally overloading the memory, although I'm not seeing any significant console errors.

#### What I tried

- **Using a `Transport.scheduleRepeat` with a callback**: (similar to this [Medium article](https://medium.com/geekculture/creating-a-step-sequencer-with-tone-js-32ea3002aaf5#d7bc) resulting in the same laggy, muting behavior
- **Using an `async` call to handle `Sequence` playback toggle**: (similar to [this CodeSandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/fw9vt?file=/src/App.js) resulting in the same laggy, muting behavior
- **Using an `Array.forEach` or `for` loop to manually loop the sequence**: failed to keep the timing in sync without `Tone` timing control
- **Using a `ref` to keep track of `Sequence` while continuously disposing the prior beat**: (modified on [this CodeSandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/sequencer-demo-wjgg4?file=/src/Sequencer.js) resulting in the same laggy, muting behavior. This is what's currently in the working code.

#### Code snippet

It's built with `React` and `TypeScript`. The main App portion is shown below. [You can view the full working code at this CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/tonejs-sequencer-exploration-ixetox?file=/src/App.tsx).

**I am a complete beginner in `Tone.js` although fairly proficient in `React`. Any guidance and insights will be highly appreciated.**

I understand the data handling, DOM handling, and other aspects of the app are also pretty clumsy, and hopefully they won't be what's causing this issue.

```js
function App() {
  type Loop = {
    dispose: any;
  };
  const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = React.useState(false);
  const [currentBeat, setCurrentBeat] = React.useState(0);
  const [currentBPM, setCurrentBPM] = React.useState(120);
  const [noteMatrix, setNoteMatrix] = React.useState(defaultNoteMatrix);
  const [currentScale, setCurrentScale] = React.useState(SCALES.major);
  const synth = new Tone.PolySynth().toDestination();
  const loop = React.useRef<Loop | null>(null);
  const noteMap = noteMatrix.map((beat) =>
    beat
      .map((note, i) => {
        return { note: currentScale[i], on: note };
      })
      .filter((note) => note.on)
      .map((item) => item.note)
  );

  const playSingleNote = (note = "") => synth.triggerAttackRelease(note, "16n");

  const tick = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>): void => {
    const currentBeat = parseFloat(e.currentTarget.dataset.beat!);
    const selectedNote = parseFloat(e.currentTarget.dataset.index!);
    const isOn = e.currentTarget.dataset.on === "1" ? 0 : 1;
    const updatedMatrix = [...noteMatrix];

    playSingleNote(currentScale[selectedNote]);
    updatedMatrix[currentBeat][selectedNote] = isOn;
    setNoteMatrix(updatedMatrix);
  };
  const reset = useCallback(() => {
    setNoteMatrix([
      [...emptyBeat],
      [...emptyBeat],
      [...emptyBeat],
      [...emptyBeat],
      [...emptyBeat],
      [...emptyBeat],
      [...emptyBeat],
      [...emptyBeat],
      [...emptyBeat],
      [...emptyBeat],
      [...emptyBeat],
      [...emptyBeat],
      [...emptyBeat],
      [...emptyBeat],
      [...emptyBeat],
      [...emptyBeat]
    ]);
    setIsPlaying(false);
    Tone.Transport.stop();
  }, []);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    Tone.Transport.loop = false;
    Tone.Transport.on("stop", () => setCurrentBeat(0));
  });
  React.useEffect(() => {
    Tone.Transport.bpm.value = currentBPM;
  }, [currentBPM]);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (loop.current) {
      loop.current.dispose();
    }
    loop.current = new Tone.Sequence(
      (time, beat) => {
        setCurrentBeat(beat);
        synth.triggerAttackRelease(noteMap[beat], "16n", time);
      },
      [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
      "16n"
    ).start(0);
  }, [noteMap, isPlaying]);
  const togglePlay = React.useCallback(() => {
    Tone.context.resume();
    Tone.Transport.toggle();
    setIsPlaying((isPlaying) => !isPlaying);
  }, []);
  return (
    <>
      <GridStyle>
        <div className="beat">
          {currentScale.map((note, i) => (
            <div className="head" key={i}>
              {note}
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
        {noteMatrix.map((beat, i) => (
          <div className="beat" key={i} data-active={currentBeat === i ? 1 : 0}>
            {currentScale.map((note, j) => (
              <button
                className="note"
                key={j}
                onClick={tick}
                data-note={note}
                data-on={beat[j]}
                data-beat={i}
                data-index={j}
              />
            ))}
          </div>
        ))}
      </GridStyle>
      <button onClick={togglePlay}>{isPlaying ? "Stop" : "Play"}</button>
      <button onClick={reset}>Clear</button>
      Scale
      <select
        name="scale"
        id="scale"
        defaultValue="major"
        onChange={(e) => setCurrentScale(SCALES[e.currentTarget.value])}
      >
        {["major", "minor", "suspended"].map((scale) => (
          <option value={scale} key={scale}>
            {scale}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
      BPM
      <select
        name="bpm"
        id="bpm"
        onChange={(e) => setCurrentBPM(parseFloat(e.currentTarget.value))}
        defaultValue={currentBPM}
      >
        {[80, 100, 120, 140, 160, 180, 200].map((bpm) => (
          <option value={bpm} key={bpm}>
            {bpm}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `synth` object is created on every render. You can move it out of `App` (or `useRef`) and everything works fine.

Another thing I noticed that no dependency list here:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  Tone.Transport.loop = false;
  Tone.Transport.on("stop", () => setCurrentBeat(0));
}, []); // <--
```

P.S. What a nice project!

Comment: Thank you for catching that! Simply moving it out of `App` did the trick. Now I can sleep well tonight, and start refining the other UX portions of this project. Very much appreciated!